How to delegate between ANTLR4 Visitors in two separate grammars?
I'm working on an ANTLR4 project where I have two separate grammars:
Transformation.g4: Contains rules to transform objects into strings with operations like toString, lowercase, and uppercase.
grammar Transformation;

transformation
    : toStringExpr
    | lowercaseExpr
    | uppercaseExpr
    | nestedTransformation
    ;

toStringExpr
    : 'toString' '(' object ')'
    ;
lowercaseExpr
    : 'lowercase' '(' transformation ')'
    ;

uppercaseExpr
    : 'uppercase' '(' transformation ')'
    ;

nestedTransformation
    : '(' transformation ')'
    ;

object
    : IDENTIFIER
    ;

IDENTIFIER
    : [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*
    ;

WS
    : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;

Predicate.g4: Contains rules for predicates, which compare transformations. For example: predicate: transformation == transformation;.
grammar Predicate;


import Transformation;

predicate
    : transformation EQUALS transformation
    ;

EQUALS
    : '==' ;

WS
    : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;

I want to compile these grammars into Java and implement visitors for both. PredicateVisitorImpl needs to rely on TransformationVisitorImpl to evaluate transformations, but I want to keep the grammars separate.
I tried to do it like this:
public class PredicateVisitorImpl extends PredicateBaseVisitor<Boolean> {
    private final TransformationVisitor transformationVisitor = new TransformationVisitor();

    @Override
    public Boolean visitTransformationComparison(PredicateParser.TransformationComparisonContext ctx) {
        String left = transformationVisitor.visit(ctx.transformation(0));
        String right = transformationVisitor.visit(ctx.transformation(1));
        
        return left.equals(right);
    }
}

However both calls to transformationVisitor.visit return null because ctx.transformation refers to the Predicate context, not Transformation
Are there clean ways to achieve this? I would like to keep the grammars separate.
I’ve considered re-parsing the transformation string inside PredicateVisitorImpl using TransformationParser, but this seems inefficient.

Your grammars define a topologic order: the "top-level" grammar is Predicate.g4 and the imported grammar is Transformation.g4. When you generate the parser/lexer/listener/visitor for Predicate.g4, all the rules in Transformation.g4 are literally inserted into a super grammar, and the listener/visitor generated from that will contain methods for all rules. "Top-level" grammars are run through the Antlr Tool. A non-top-level grammar should not be run through the Antlr Tool because the generated code is non-sequester and cannot be used.

Unfortunately, this is not how ANTLR works. The import actually brings the entire grammar into your grammar.
If you check the PredicateBaseVisitor function, you will find the functions for the TransformationVisitor as well, because the whole grammar is imported.
Basically, your generated code contains duplicate definitions for toString and all other rules.
One way to address this is to change the predicate syntax to use brackets for transformations. The predicate lexer would then create a string from all characters between the brackets, and the predicate parser could parse this string using the Transformation parser.
